# Multiple image picker from Facebook Album

Tags: android, facebook, image, picker

I am looking for a multiple image simple picker for a Facebook Album (from Facebook SDK).
I got some photos from a Facebook Album and i would let the user pick multiple photos in this one (max 5 photos) but i didn't find any solution.
In fact, the important is to allow the user to select a photo object from an URL, cause facebook photo object provides an URL (in fact, multiples URLs).

All solutions i found are about a gallery image picker from filesystem or camera, but i don't want that, i want the user selects from a list of image URLs and only from this one.

I am not an expert of Android ;-)